# Left-align Contents of a UWP Button.Flyout

Tags: xaml, uwp, alignment, flyout

I'm unable to left-align the contents of a `Flyout`.

[image]

Windows seems to automatically right-align flyout contents that display on the right side of the window. I tried setting the `HorizontalAlignment` property of the children, setting the `Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle` property `HorizontalContentAlignment`, and other `HorizontalContentAlignment` properties without success.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
            FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
   <!-- Settings menu -->
   <Button.Flyout>
      <Flyout>
         <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
            <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
               <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled"/>
               <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
               <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/><!-- No -->
            </Style>
         </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
         <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left"><!-- No -->
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalTextAlignment="Left">Settings</TextBlock><!-- No -->
            …
   </Button.Flyout>
</StackPanel>
```

I expect the flyout contents to align left, but they stay on the right.

Comment: I create a sample with above code but I could no reproduce the issue, could mind share a [mcve]?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Thank you for taking a look! I added the `StackPanel` which was causing the issue in the problem description (which helped me find the solution as well).

Comment: Don't mention it, If you have solve the issue please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a reproducible example made me realize my error. The property `FlowDirection` was accidentally set as `RightToLeft` in a parent `StackPanel`. Reverting this solves the problem.